# How to put the maintenance page up/down using haproxy load balancer through the VSTS release defintion?

Tags: iis, haproxy, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am working on VSTS DevOps, currently I used haproxy load balancer for manually putting maintenance page before deploying the web application into specified IIS website. After that, go to the site and rename the _app.offline.htm to app.offline.htm vice-versa.

Example code:

> sudo /etc/haproxy/maint_page_up.sh – to put maintenance page up before work starts
>
> sudo /etc/haproxy/maint_page_down.sh – to take maintenance page down after work is done

But I want the above process through the VSTS release level, currently I used the IIS web app Deploy task to deploy the website into server this task contains the option as Take App Offline but right I don’t want to use that option for putting offline page before deployment. But I want to put the maintenance page using haproxy load balancer.

Comment: Do you mean you just need to call that script to do it in local? If so, you can call thses script files (maint_page_up.sh, maint_page_down.sh) during release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After did some Research on this, I find out VSTS task named as "[SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/deploy/ssh)" task by using this task I am able to run the shell commands for put the maintenance page up before start to deploy the web application and after successfully deployed my web application, then I remove the maintenance page.

Sample Commands:

> sudo /etc/haproxy/maint_page_up.sh
>
> sudo /etc/haproxy/maint_page_down.sh